# Conditionally make MySQL query results a Hyperlink in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to have a certain cell of a mysql query be a hyperlink to a user profile that I will eventually create. I can get everything to be a link, but not just the Name fields. Right now i'm just having everything displayed that is linked to the primary key(playerID) for test purposes.

I know the issue is here:`if (($cell->name)=='fName')`

```
<?php

// db login info
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db_login.php';

// connecting, selecting, & error messages
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($db))
    die("Can't select database");

// get parsed playerID
$id = $_GET[id];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                       FROM players p
                       LEFT JOIN baseball b ON p.playerID = b.playerID
                       LEFT JOIN hockey h ON p.playerID = h.playerID
                       LEFT JOIN football f ON p.playerID = f.playerID
                       WHERE p.playerID = '$id';");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1'><tr>";

// printing column headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
        }

echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($row as $cell){

        if (($cell->name)=='fName'){
            echo "<td><a href=\"info.php?id={$row[0]}\">$cell</a></td>";
                    }
        else {
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                    }
            }
    echo "</tr>\n";

}
echo "</table>";
// clear result variable
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($result);

echo "<a href=\"testing.php\">Back</a>";
?>
```

Comment: echo "$row[0]"; is bad! either split the variables from the text or enclose arrays in curly brackets ie echo "hello".$row[0]; or echo "Hello {$row[0]}"

Comment: On a side note, mysql_query is deprecated and opens the doors to sql injections. Try looking at prepared queries from the msqli or pdo librairies.

Comment: On a side note mysql_query is not deprecated yet and opens the same doors as msqli or pdo librairies do.

Comment: Correcting (or enlarging on) Your Common Sense's comment, mysql_query *is* deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the future - check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php for the details. See the RED BOX?

Comment: Definitely will look into msqli/pdo. Did not realize that the mysql_query was deprecated. Thanks for that. Also added {} to row[0]. Thanks for that as well!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you need something like this:

```
<?php

// db login info
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db_login.php';

// connecting, selecting, & error messages
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($db))
    die("Can't select database");

// get parsed playerID
$id = $_GET[id];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                       FROM players p
                       LEFT JOIN baseball b ON p.playerID = b.playerID
                       LEFT JOIN hockey h ON p.playerID = h.playerID
                       LEFT JOIN football f ON p.playerID = f.playerID
                       WHERE p.playerID = '$id';");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

print_r ($result);

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1'><tr>";
echo "<td><b>SCHMOHAWKS</b></td><tr>";

// printing column headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
        }
echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
// koala note: use mysql_fetch_assoc instead
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) != FALSE){
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable

    foreach($row as $cell_name => $cell){

        // cell name will be the associative array's key
        // so things are as simple as this:
        if ($cell_name=='fName'){
            echo "<td><a href=\"info.php?id=$row[0]\">$cell</a></td>";
                    }
        else {
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                    }
            }
    echo "</tr>\n";

}
echo "</table>";
// clear result variable
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($result);

echo "<a href=\"testing.php\">Back</a>";
```

Comment: When I add in your changes, the results of my query vastly differ, all fields aren't complete and the values in the fields aren't right.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** You should probably use PDO instead for this, since the functions you are using have been deprecated if I have understood correctly.*

---

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get an associative array which will include the column names as keys. Loop over the array and check the key for the special cases you want to handle differently.

In your loop I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this should work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        if ($name == 'fName')
            printf('<td><a href="info.php?id=%u">%s</a></td>', $row['id'], htmlspecialchars($value));
        else
            printf('<td>%s</td>', htmlspecialchars($value));
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

The important changes are:

- Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead so you get the column name rather than column number as key.
- Add `$name =>`  to foreach loop to get access to the name during looping.
- Use `printf` and `htmlspecialchars` to print your values more safely.

Comment: I'm trying to get just the fName field to be a link. The loop is just printing out the results of the select * query in a single row table. I inserted these corrections and they didn't appear to work. mysql_fetch_assoc is something I will definitely research as in the future i'll need access to the column names as well. Thanks.